# Storing Images in server using ExpressJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

### I am new to programming and I am trying to store images which i recieve as POST request from my Client to my server

---

1. **Client**:: `Android`
2. **Server**:: `ExpressJS running on AWS`
3. **Database i am using** :: `MySQL`

---

***In MySQL DATABASE***

1. **I have created a Database in mySQL**:: `restaurants`
2. **There is a table named**:: `ReataurantGalleryImages`

**I am using relative path to store the images**

---

**I have to store the images in the place as below which is a public directory to store images in express**

```
/public/images
```

---

**My Express Code that i have tried**::

```
var express = require('express')
 , async = require('async')
 , http = require('http')
 , mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: '******',
   password: "******",
   database: '**********'
});

connection.connect();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1234);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


app.post('/Name/',function(request,response,next){


app.use(express.bodyParser());

   var keyName = new Buffer(request.query.Key, 'base64').toString('binary');
   var keyImage = new Buffer(request.query.Key2, 'base64').toString('binary');
   var name_of_restaurants;
   async.series( [

       function(callback) {

          connection.query('INSERT INTO RestaurantGalleryImages (Images,RestName) VALUES (?,?)', [keyImage,keyName], function (err, rows, fields) 
              {
                      console.log('Connection result error ' + err);        
                      callback();
              });
       }

  // Send the response
] );
} );


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

---

### My Queries::

- Am i correct with my code
- How it the name gets stored in table for the varchar field (`Images`)
  and file for the location
  `/MyDirectory/projects/MyProject/public/images`
- How mapping of whole thing takes place

---

**Hope i am clear** 
.
**Thanks**

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the datatype for "Images"?

Comment: @ tsturzl ...I am not understanding the concept .... when we post image to server how the image goes and sits in /public/images and the name of the image in the table ... for example a varchar column "Images" in the table "RestaurantGalleryImages" in my example ....any input on this !

Comment: Well unless you're using a BLOB datatype in your mysql database you can't store images in the database, and in fact you probably shouldn't regardless for several reasons: It's messy and slow, reading the filesystem is faster than querying a database, and if your mysql server is on another machine or VM it will have to transport large sums of data over your local network creating a bottleneck. What you should do is create files in a folder to save image data to and store the path to that file in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing images in the database is bad practice, as it consumes more resources of your database. Rather, you should try storing images on disk and store the path in the table.

Try something like this:

```js
    app.post('/upload'),function(req,res){
       req.form.complete(function(err,fields,files){
          async.series([
             function(cb){
                fs.rename(files.image.path+files.image.name,'./public/image/'+files.image.name,function(err){

                connection.query('INSERT INTO RestaurantGalleryImages (Images,RestName) VALUES (?,?)', [fields.name,files.image.path+'/'+files.filename],
                   function(err){
                      cb();
                 });
                 });
          );
        });
    });
```

You'd then POST to /Name, for example `http://127.0.0.1/Name`. 
Ex.

```
<form name='form' action='/Name' method='post'>
   <input type='text' name='name'>
   <input type='file' name='image'>
</form
```

Comment: Note that you might want to check file type for security reasons.

Comment: @ tsturzl .....Thanks, According to your code - What should i edit for [fields.name,files.image.path+'/'+files.filename]

Comment: I don't mean to insult, but I think the biggest issue here is that you're lacking knowledge of how node works in general, therefore creating the confusion about expressjs. To me it seems that you understand that node is asynchronous, but you don't fully understand how to leverage that. Also consider doing some reading on the HTTP application layer.